# Update ListView with db-models data

Tags: react-native

I would like to generate my view with my data created with db-models :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-db-models

But there is the problem : nothing appends, my view stay empty. 
1 ) The size of db (for loop) is equal to 0 (but it must be 8 after my **DB.bills.get_all().**

**Constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  var bdd = [];
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(bdd)
 };
}
```

**ComponentDidMount()**

```
componentDidMount() {
console.log("START");

let self = this;
var db = [];

DB.bills.get_all(function(result) {
  db = result;
  console.log(db);
});

  let newArray = self.state.dataSource._dataBlob.s1.slice();
  for(var i = 0; i<Object.keys(db).length ; i++){
    newArray[i] = {
      ...self.state.dataSource[i],
      field: JSON.stringify(db),
    };
    console.log("i : " + i + " db : " + db);
  }

  self.setState({dataSource: self.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
  });
        console.log("DS : ", this.state.dataSource);
  console.log("END");
}
```

There is the **console.log(db) in my DB.bills.get_all()**

```
Object {totalrows: 7, autoinc: 8, rows: Object}
autoinc : 8
rows : Object
 1 : Object
  creditor:"M. Alixe"
  month:"Décembre"
  picture:"https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/8YftpB3rQGA5S.png"
  price:"700"
  type:"Maquettes UI"
  year:"2016"
  _id:1
  __proto__:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
7:Object
__proto__:Object
totalrows:7
__proto__:Object
```

I'm on it since 2 days. Please help me ^^"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `DB.bills.get_all` function is asynchronous. By the time you get `result`, you have already calculated `newArray` and set your state. You need to wait for the `result` before calculating `newArray` and cloning your dataSource. Try putting the code after `DB.bills.get_all` inside the callback function.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem !